# .htaccess complex rewrite rule partially working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite the URLS based on the requests.

**From this url structure:**

```
http://example.com/index.php?image=folder/sub-folder/image-name-goes-here
```

**To this url structure:**

```
http://example.com/sub-folder/image-name-goes-here
```

i need to eliminate this part **index.php?image=folder**

so far i got these rules by search the Stackoverflow existing answers

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ /index.php?image=$1 [L]    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?image=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

**Got this result by applying above rules:**

```
http://example.com/folder/sub-folder/image-name-goes-here
```

I'm lost at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You may use these rules:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?image=folder/([^\&\ ]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/[\w-]+)/?$ index.php?image=folder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. The redirect part is not working as it should be, but by manually entering the URL it works. Can you please tell me what you did there to help me understand better, so that i can customize it further.

Comment: If redirect is working by manually entering URL in browser, then it might be a browser cache issue. Change is to match `image=` parameter with `folder/` text and use the same in 2nd rule while rewriting since you want to mask `folder/` from clients. I suggest you test `http://example.com/index.php?image=folder/sub-folder/image-name-goes-here` in a new browser.